# Set up ruby gems proxy through a proxy pac file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Anyone can set up ruby gems proxy through a proxy pac file?

I can't use flag -p to do something like

```
 gem install rails -p http://wolfbyte:secret@pigsy:8080
```

because .pac is a script.

Any tips?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can download the PAC file and examine it for the address of the proxy server.

For example, a file containing:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return "PROXY pigsy:8080";
}
```

would require you to enter

```
gem install rails -p http://wolfbyte:secret@pigsy:8080
```

For more complex PAC files, use [ruby-pac](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-pac)